# Update Notification for multiple messages

Tags: android, android-notifications

Below is my code which generates notification when new message arrives in my application,

### Code

```
 private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int counter = 0;
        counter++;

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MessageActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(counter, notification);

    }
```

When I receive multiple messages, there are multiple notifications.

### e.g

Suppose I receive 3 new messages then there are 3 individual notifications. But I want only single notification for multiple messages. When I receive multiple messages then notification should be updated as we see in **WhatsApp** .  How can I do this?

Comment: set Uniqe Id to your notification.

Comment: @MD: u mean in this line notificationManager.notify(counter, notification);  ???

Comment: exactly your counter value change every time but instead of you can fixed this with unique id. i mean unique int value

Comment: ya that's f9 buddy but I want the previous message should be there...

Comment: means with the previous message, new message should be appended

Comment: No. that's not possible

Comment: u please read this official [Updating notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Comment: ok. then do u know how the WhatsApp's notification works? any idea...

Comment: sorry i dont know about this.

Comment: okok... np... I'm going to implement that type of notification... will let u know when I'm done with it...

Comment: By the way your question is nice. best of luck...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47212/discussion-between-m-d-and-anil-bhatiya)

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple messages, for example in a JsonArray, you can loop through the Array and create a notification for each item in your array. The Notification created in the loop can be updated by setting the same Unique_ID. If you want to display a number to show the amount of messages in this Notification (i.e a number for unread messages) create a counter and increase it by 1 in your loop. Based on the targeted Android-SDK use for example NotificationCompat.InboxStyle (needs android.v4.support library) or Notification.InboxStyle to display multilined Notifications and use InboxStyle.addLine to add the content of each of your Arrayitems in your loop.